# Class Templates Partial Specialiazation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

The following code compiles successfully, and I fail to understand why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Template definition
template <typename T1, typename T2> class stack
{
};

// Template specialization
template <> class stack <float, float>
{
};

int main ()
{
  stack <char, char> objStack;
  return 0;
}
```

Doesn't Partial Specialization mean that we can use the class for some ***particular*** data types, which we specify in the specializations?

There is no specialized class for ***char*** here, and if it is going to compile with any kind of data types then what is the purpose of specialization?

Comment: I have edited this and other answers to include more tags. In the future, tag as fully as possible; be sure to include the programming language.

Comment: @GMan Thanks, I thought the "specific" tag would make the search better, since C++ is a very broad term, anyway you are senior here :)

Comment: You're partially right. Add the most general tags, then get more and more specific. By adding C++, people interested in C++ questions will see it. By adding C++ and templates, you'll get a group that not only likes C++, but likes answering questions about templates as well. So you're right, specific is good, but build on a base first. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template specialization is for when you want to do something specifically different for specific template parameters. The compiler will instantiate anything non-speficied from the original template.

This is useful for when you want different behavior for a specific data type, but can also be used for more complex pattern matching, such as changing the behavior for pointer types, or `const` types:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_pointer { static bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct is_pointer<T*> { static bool value = true; };

template <typename T>
struct is_const { static bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct is_const<const T>  { static bool value = true; };

// later, try this:
assert(is_pointer<int*>::value == true);
assert(is_pointer<int>::value == false);
```

So, long story short: don't bother specifying your template unless you've got something special to do with a certain parameter, that you can't generalize into the base-template. Template specialization is just a rather hardcore form of pattern-matching which can be used for both good and evil.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I was under a conception that partial specializations are to be used when you want the class to function ONLY for the specified data types, nothing else. Your example has made the concept clear.

Comment: And also there is a disadvantage in normal function overloading, I think, (correct me if I am wrong) if we overload a normal function with "int" and then with "short", and we call the same function like: f(2), which of the above implementations should get called? This problem will not occur with the class templates since we have to make an object of the class like :`stack <short, short> objStack;`. Ah well, I have yet not seen how it goes with "function templates", so I shouldn't comment on this perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Template specialization means taking a general purpose template and adding a type or function that will be used for a special set of types.  Partial specialization is when you have a template type or function with more than one parameter and you do not specify all of the parameters in your specialization.

In your example, this function is the general template.

```
// Template definition
template <typename T1, typename T2> class stack
{
};
```

It will be instantiated for any types you give it EXCEPT for if you give two floats.  In the case that you give two floats as parameters this template

```
// Template specialization
template <> class stack <float, float>
{
};
```

will be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks to you too, the concept is clear for me now :) Newbies can't vote up a post :rolleyes:

Comment: No problem, glad to hear that you have the idea down now;-)

Comment: Here's an off topic question: Do the *other* posters get notifies *anyhow*, of comments posted *anywhere* in the thread?

Comment: I don't think so.  At least not by default.  I could be a setting somewhere though.  There is a meta-stackoverflow site where I think you could ask question and get an answer from someone that will be correct.

Comment: and I find it ridiculous, *"Just voted this up for you"* This comment by you Jonathan was not shown in my "responses" page!! :mad:

Comment: @Itc @Jonathan Can this be called a template definition as well as a specification: 
`template <typename T1> class stack <T1, char>
{
};` ?

Comment: Ok I understood it myself, it is not the case, it gets a compilation error.